# Is there a formula for importing multiple rows of cells in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a main worksheet where I import cells from other google sheets using:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("url"; "Sheet1!A1:A5")
```

And a simple overview of my sheets:

Main sheet:

- A1:A5 / Data
- A6 Another formula
- A7:A11 / Data

Sheet1:

- A1:A5 / Data
- A6 Nothing
- A7:A11 / Data

I know that IMPORTRANGE doesn't retrieve empty cells so I tried to import A1:A11, but it's not possible because it exceeds the data in A6. The simple solution is to use:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("url"; "Sheet1!A1:A5")
=IMPORTRANGE("url"; "Sheet1!A7:A11")
```

But I have multiple columns, rows and different urls, so I wonder if there is like an "&" solution so I don't have to write a formula for each line. Something like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("url1"; "Sheet1!A1:A5&A7:A11&A13:A19")
=IMPORTRANGE("url2"; "Sheet1!A1:A5&A7:A11&A13:A19")
=IMPORTRANGE("url3"; "Sheet1!A1:A5&A7:A11&A13:A19")
```

In a scenario like this, I just need to retrieve the different urls.

Thanks on behalf

[image: Main sheet with all data]Main sheet with all data.

[image: Main sheet and sheet1 explained]Main sheet and sheet1 explained

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining multiple spreadsheets in one using IMPORTRANGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657470/combining-multiple-spreadsheets-in-one-using-importrange)

Comment: please check both answers of that question. The first one, puts all the importranges in one place, the second answer users `QUERY` to remove the blank rows based on particular columns.

Comment: Thanks @Marios. I read that post, and it's still a better solution then mine. But I still have to get the url for every IMPORTRANGE. And maybe that's my answer - it's not possible,

Comment: But how else can the formula know which spreadsheets to fetch it you don't provide the URL for these spreadsheets?

Comment: In my head I thought there was a solution like this: =IMPORTRANGE("URL"; "Sheet1! Cell A1:A5 + Cell A7:A11"). Where to formula gets the Url and spreadsheets in the beginning, and then you can just fill in with multiple ranges from the same columns, with space between.

Comment: @Marios added some pictures!